# Is there a specific Sympy function to simplify an equation?

Tags: python, sympy

According to the Sympy documentation, the `simplify` function of the Sympy package is a general simplification function that should be replaced by other, more specific functions for each use case. Quoting the documentation, it says:

> Simplification is not a well defined term and the exact strategies
> this function tries can change in the future versions of SymPy. If
> your algorithm relies on "simplification" (whatever it is), try to
> determine what you need exactly

So far I've found several specific simplification functions using the [Documentation for simplification](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html), like functions to simplify expressions with radicals, and so on.

What I'm looking for now (and isn't present in the linked documentation), is for a function to simplify equations. The `simplify` function works fine, but I'm wondering is there a function specific to simplify equations?

For example, the equation 3x - 2 = 5x - 6, can be simplified to 4 = 2x, or even simpler x = 2. This is done by Sympy, but so far only with the generic `simplify` function.

```
import sympy
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
eq1 = sympy.Eq(3*x - 2, 5*x - 6)
eq2 = sympy.simplify(eq1)
```

At the end, the var `eq2` has the value `Eq(x, 2)`, which means that the simplification was successful. But only the `simplify` function returns this simplification. I've tried using many of the other sympy functions, such as `cancel`, `factor`, `expand`, `collect`, to no avail so far.

Is there a Sympy function whose specific use is to simplify equations? Or this is solely done by the `simplify` function? Thank you.

Comment: The documentation is right though, there are many types of simplification (and for each, many ways to perform it, each with different goals). I think it might be useful here to consider whether simplification is required or simply just solving a linear equation ? (if the latter, then SymPy has [`solve(..)`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html) )

Comment: @wsdookadr the thing is that in linear equations in two variables, the process of simplification incidentally leads to a solution, but on other types of equation it doesn't lead to a solution and yet those equations can be simplified. My purpose is not to solve the equations but to simplify them, regardless of if a solution is found in that process. Edit: Happy Holidays and thanks for your comment.

Comment: It would depend quite a bit on the kind of simplifications you want to perform. In linear systems I know there's some techniques like [Gauss-Jordan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) , [LU-decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) , [QR-decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition). Do you have in mind one of those, or something else? Thank you btw, Happy Holidays to you as well :)